# python find method doesn't work for "/" here

Tags: python, python-2.7

consider the code below

```
#!/usr/bin/python
url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389923/python-find-method-doesnt-work-for-here"
print url.find("/",8)
```

the output you will get is 24, but the answer must be 3. Isn't it ?

Comment: Please read about [`str.find`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) first.

Answer (score 2):

This finds the first ***index*** of the substring `/`, *starting the search from index 8*.

You probably thought it was counting the number of occurrences, rather than finding the position, but you would not misunderstand this if you read the docstring:

```
Docstring:
S.find(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int

Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found,
such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

Return -1 on failure.
```

Now, to get the "3" I think you were probably looking for:

```
>>> url[8:].count('/')
3
```

Comment: @user3393168 `str.find` returns the index, not count.

Answer (score 1):

The output is correct, why were you expecting a `3`? look:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389923/python-find-method-doesnt-work-for-here
^  ^    ^               ^
0  3    8              24
```

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find), `url.find("/", 8)` is looking for the index of the first occurrence of `"/"` *after* the 8th index, and that happens to be in the 24th index. Quoting the docs (emphasis mine):

```
string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]])
```

> Return the lowest **index** in *s* where the substring *sub* is found such that *sub* is wholly contained in `s[start:end]`. Return `-1` on failure. Defaults for *start* and *end* and interpretation of negative values is the same as for slices.

Perhaps you meant to use [`count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count)?

```
url.count('/', 8)
=> 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the use of [`str.find`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find). It finds the `index` of a certain substring (i.e. its *position*), not the number of times that it occurred like you seem to want. You want to use (surprise, surprise) [`str.count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count).

For example:

```
>>> url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389923/python-find-method-doesnt-work-for-here"
>>> url.count('/', 8)
3
```

Which seems to be the output that you desire.

Answer (score 0):

The `find` method in Python returns an index of a particular character in a string.  One of the optional parameters is the position in the string of which you want to start.  In your command, you say:

```
print url.find("/", 8)
```

You are telling it to print the index of the first occurrence of a slash, starting on the 8th character.  In this string, that occurrence is on character 24.

From the docs:

```
string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]])

Return the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found such that sub 
is wholly contained in s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure. Defaults for start 
and end and interpretation of negative values is the same as for slices.
```

More in the documentation here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find

It seems that you are, instead, trying to find the number of occurrences of a character after a starting point.  To do this, you can use the `.count` method.  Here is some sample code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389923/python-find-method-doesnt-work-for-here"
print url.count( '/', 8)
# should print 3
```

More in the docs here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count